# Can't insert record into Database without any Postback asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, entity-framework

Hi i am having a problem inserting records into database. I am using entity framework as my back end. I have the following code. I am unable to figure out the actual problem in my code since showing no error message when try to run.

**.aspx**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />       
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script></script>

<script type="text/javascript">      
function SaveRecord() {  
            //Get control's values  
            var Name = $.trim($('#<%=txtCompanyName.ClientID %>').val());
            var msg = "";
            //check for validation  
            if (Name == '') {
                msg += "Please enter Name";
            }
            if (msg.length == 0) {
                //Jquery Ajax call to server side method  
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "company_master.aspx/InsertCompany",
                    data: "{'Name':'" + Name + "'}",

                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.d == true) {
                            $('#lblMsg').text("Saved successfully");
                            //Clear/Reset controls  
                            $('#txtCompanyName').val('');
                            //$('#ddlDeptId').val("0");
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#lblMsg').text("Not Saved");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                        $('#lblMsg').text("Error: " + error);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#lblMsg').html('');
                $('#lblMsg').html(msg);
            }
        }

</script>

  <div>  
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Company Name" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
    <button type="submit" onclick="SaveRecord()"/>Submit
 </div>
```

**C# Code Behind:**

```
using System.Web.Services;


[WebMethod]
public static bool InsertCompany(string Name)
{
   bool status = false;
   try
    {
        var company = new CompanyMaster
        {
            CompanyName = Name
        };

        using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            context.CompanyMaster.Add(company);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        status = true;
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw ex;
   }

        return status;
}
```

Kindly help me to overcome this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the desired behavior and what is your problem?

Comment: Sometimes, a problem overwhelms that you lack the expression that will bring the solution. Can you detail what the actual problem is

Comment: Ty for ur reply......data do not get saved when i submit the record. Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: is the response 200 OK?

Comment: Also your try catch is completely unnecessary. And by saying `throw ex;` instead of `throw;` you kill your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

No problem your code. can you look in  console of chrome?

Request returned 404 or 500.

You can check url :

```
url: "/company_master.aspx/InsertCompany",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button  type="button" onclick="SaveRecord(); return false">Submit</button>
```

Also, check in your browser console, if there's any other error

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<input type='button'>` and see how that works. There may be a submission conflicting with the event that sends the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code, and it works without tweaking. The only difference is I have this

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

and the div is contained within that. Use default browser as google chrome, and debug using chrome developer tools, it saves time.